# Как отличить частицу «правда» от вводного слова «правда»?

Tags: вводные-слова

Диалог (первая встреча ученицы, бывшей воспитанницы детдома,  и ее «гувернера-учителя»)

*–  Вас чё,  **правда** «сэр Николас»  зовут?*

*– Зовите меня «Николай Александрович». Слово «что» произносится как «што».  Вместо просторечного **«правда»** лучше сказать **«в самом деле».***

*… Она украдкой полюбовалась на свои часики.*

*– Это французские, с настоящими бриллиантами. Папа купил. **Правда, красивые?** Ой, извините, я хотела сказать: **в самом деле красивые?***

*Николас вздохнул. О, великий и могучий. **Сам черт в тебе ногу сломит**.*

Николас – русский по происхождению и англичанин по рождению. Оба языка он знает в совершенстве, а русскую маргинальную лексику даже изучал специально (по совету педагога-лингвиста, потом ему это очень пригодилось). Но сейчас он, кажется, попал в затруднительное положение, поэтому требуется ваша помощь.

Действительно, как отличить частицу от вводного слова, да еще объяснить ситуацию подростку? В обоих случаях  у нас вопросительное предложение.

Из Справочника по пунктуации:
**ПРАВДА**, 1. **Частица** (обычно перед сказуемым). Выражает утверждение, уверенность, а также употребляется **при вопросе, требующем подтверждения**. Не требует постановки знаков препинания. 2. **Вводное слово**. То же, что «действительно, в самом деле, верно».

Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть, отличие в невозможности перестановки частицы? А вводное слово можно переставить. Красивые, правда?

Comment: Спасибо, Nadezhda,  наблюдение верное, но очень  ч а с т н о го   характера, а у Николаса задание особое. Он должен  «привести девочку Миру  в порядок» за очень короткий срок – уже через несколько дней будет прием в честь ее дня рождения, а как она себя ведет, как  говорит! Неграмотно построенные фразы, вульгаризмы. Конечно, она очень старается.  Поняла, что «правда» и «в самом деле» – это синонимы, но различаются по стилю.  Применила новые знания на практике – и тут же сделала смысловую ошибку. Что дальше-то говорить?

Comment: Можно, к примеру, заметить, что ее вторая фраза верная (правда, красивые?), но если перенести ударение на первое  слово, то опять будет просторечной.  А почему при использовании «в самом деле» изменился смысл фразы, разве это не синонимы, как она думала? Здесь много вопросов, но носители языка без труда справляются с ними. Мне кажется, что вопрос для ясности  пока лучше  «замять», это дело не одного дня.  Вот и Николас представил себя сантехником, который говорит: «Ну  не знаю, командир, сам гляди, работы тут много, а у меня смена кончается».

Comment: Поэтому ответил: «Сделаю, что могу. Зевать она будет с закрытым ртом, это я вам гарантирую».

Comment: Научить грамотно говорить за короткий срок невозможно, как невозможно научиться играть на скрипке за пару дней! Культура речи впитывается из окружения и книг.)

Comment: Тут вот что интересно. У девочки  не было возможности «впитать культуру речи» – ни приличного окружения, ни хороших книг. Тем не менее она с точки зрения смысла правильно строит две фразы, только в первом случае использует разговорный стиль. Это я к тому говорю, что носители языка могут выбирать правильный речевой вариант  интуитивно. Но вот вмешивается сэр Николас, имеющий прекрасное образование, прочитавший множество книг,   и ученица делает уже смысловую ошибку. Парадокс! Какую мы можем дать оценку?

Comment: В народных пословицах вот что об этом говорится: Недоученный хуже неученого. Полузнание хуже незнания. Стоит и об этом задуматься.

Comment: "...и ученица делает уже смысловую ошибку. Парадокс!" - Потому что она пытается пользоваться малознакомыми ей словами, она не знает всех оттенков их значений и с какими словами их можно сочетать. Ей удобнее использовать другую лексику. Вас че, реально сэр Николас зовут? Может, сэру Николасу с этой стороны подойти к объяснениям, он же изучал маргинальную лексику.) Можно поискать аналогии.

Answer (score 3):

На первый взгляд может показаться крайне сложным отличить утвердительные частицы (действительно, правда, точно) от вводных слов меры уверенности. Может показаться, что придется разбираться в каких-то тонких эманациях, но разница между ними — огромна! При вводных словах делается коротенькое отступление, сообщающее о мере уверенности говорящего в чем-то; утвердительные частицы же категорично пресекают какое-либо сомнение, которое ясно из контекста.

— Эта красавица его жена?
— Да, это правда его жена.

— Он говорит, что Тадлтон — это большой город на севере Англии, а я думаю, что это небольшой шахтерский поселок.
— Нет, это правда большой город.

— Я не видел хороших картин написанных им.
— Он правда искусных художник. Поверь мне.

— Я не нравлюсь тебе.
— Ты правда мне очень нравишься, но я тебя бросаю.

Вопросы с частицей «правда» можно заменить следующим образом:
Это правда его жена? = Можете ли вы категорично пресечь мое сомнение по поводу того, что это его жена?
Это правда большой город? = Можете ли вы категорично пресечь мое сомнение по поводу того, что это большой город?
Итак, еще раз, утвердительные частицы используются говорящим для того, чтобы категорично пресекать чьё-либо сомнение. Это действительно большой город. Это точно большой город. Это правда большой город.

Теперь слово «правда» как вводное. Я называю эту подсовокупность вводных слов «предворяющие важное, резкое, откровенное, постыдное». Следовало бы расписать про эту подсовокупность, но мой ответ и так выйдет большим.  Вот несколько примеров, для различения вводных и частиц:

— Вот, где я живу.
— ...Квартира, правда, небольшая, но лучше чем ничего. (слово «правда» предворяет слегка неудобную информацию, которая следует после этого слова)

— Я думал, что они врут, когда говорят, что этот богач живет в конуре.
— Квартира правда небольшая, ни метра лишнего пространства. (категорическое пресечение  сомнений)

— Как прошла твоя вечеринка?
— Нормально. Народу, правда, не шибко много было. (слово «правда» предворяет слегка неудобную информацию)

— Я слышал, что на вечеринке было мало людей.
— Народу правда не шибко много было. (категорическое пресечение сомнений)

— Ты согрешил на этой неделе, парень?
— Нет... Правда, я разорил сорочье гнездо. (слово «правда» предворяет слегка неудобную информацию)

— Ты правда сделал это, хулиганьё?
— Я правда разорил сорочье гнездо. (категорическое пресечение сомнений)

По поводу союза. Я и так много времени пишу это сообщение. Чтобы ответить точно, мне нужно рассмотреть много примеров. Я нашел только одно, где «правда» — 100 процентов союз.
Погуляли хорошо, правда устали. (ничего важного, ключевого, резкого, откровенного, а «правда» здесь безусловный эквивалент уступительного союза «хотя»)

Comment: А в таком предложении: 
"Погуляли хорошо, устали, правда.". Правда уже не союз? А ведь смысл тот же, если не лезть в тонкие эманации.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. Я сначала написала свой вариант ответа, только потом увидела ваш. Ну да ладно. Вы не возражаете, если я чуть позже (завтра, вероятно) ознакомлюсь с  ним, сейчас времени нет.

Comment: И еще такое: "Погуляли хорошо, правда сказать, устали".

Comment: Сочетание слов «устали правда» возможно, имеет какие-то тонкие стилистические отличия от «правда устали», но это все еще тот же смысл; «правда» все еще союз; а «устали правда» все еще тоже, что и «хотя устали».

Comment: По поводу «... правда сказать, устали». Никто и никогда не скажет: «... правда сказать, устали», так как вводное «правда сказать» должно употребляться перед чем-то хоть немного резким или оскорбительным, или откровенным, или постыдным. Трудно представить ситуацию, когда в том, что кто-то устал, будет что-то подобное.

Comment: Почему не скажет? Имеется в виду такой смысл:
Погуляли хорошо, а по-правде сказать, плохо.
Но я согласен, что смысл уже другой, нежели в исходном предложении. Так что этот вопрос пока отложим. Остается еще первый вопрос:
Если вы говорите, что "правда"=100%=хотя в данном предложении, почему тогда никто никогда не скажет: "Погуляли хорошо, устали, хотя".

Comment: Предложение: «... правда сказать, устали» — и «... а по-правде сказать, плохо.» — совершенно разные; как по тому, что подразумевается, так и по словам, которые используются в этих предложениях. Что это за вредные комментарии? Мне еще ответить на 100500 вредных комментариев? Я не хочу заниматься мартышкиным трудном и спорить с вами о тонких смысловых отличиях между «правда устали», «устали правда» и «хотя устали».

Comment: Хозяин барин. Не хотите не спорьте. Я хотел вас натолкнуть на какие-то мысли, ну нет так нет. Пускай будут вредные ответы без вредных комментариев

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо за ответ, он очень помог мне разобраться в теме, хотя я не могу однозначно согласиться со многими вашими утверждениями. Возможно, мы просто говорим о похожих вещах разными словами: вы  рассуждаете так, как слышите и понимаете, я же пытаюсь уложить информацию в общепринятую классификацию вводных слов. Я дополню свой ответ еще одной статьей. Составляя ее, я во многом ориентировалась на ваши взгляды, меняла и уточняла  ее структуру.

Comment: Знаете, как бывает:  хотя и не соглашаешься с собеседниками, но  свое окончательное суждение во многом проясняешь с их помощью. Вот за это я благодарна людям, которые отвечают на мои вопросы.

Comment: Я рад, что мой ответ был вам полезен. Вам спасибо за хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Злободневный вопрос. Справочники сами путаются, а вы ребёнку хотите объяснить. Вот здесь предлагается разграничение взависимости от позиции **правда** в предложении:

> ПРАВДА, союз.
>
> 1. Употребляется в функции вводного с целью подчеркнуть  правдивость высказывания, доверительное отношение к  собеседнику, с оттенком
>    уступки: Блеснула, правда, молния,  а не коса, тем не менее акробат
>    готов умереть (Ю. Олеиш);  Там, правда, якорная стоянка неудобная, но
>    все-таки займи  можно (В.Каверин).
> 2. Невводное, употребляется в функции союза уступки  (= хотя), если стоит на стыке частей сложного предложения или  между однородными
>    членами предложения, не обособляется:  У тестя был вид заправского
>    заговорщика, правда отчаянная  решимость стоила ему волнений
>    (Ю.Трифонов).  Сравни: Сколько влюбленных ходило по Тверскому
>    бульвару!  Теперь по нему идем мы. Правда, мы еще не влюбленные
>    ({О.Казаков) - стоит в начале предложения, обособляется.
> 3. Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства  образа действия в значении «вправду», не обособляется:  Слушай» а ты правда (=
>    вправду) жена Алешки Скворцова или  это розыгрыш? (Ю.Нагибин).

Другими словами, предлагается такой взгляд:

```
Я спрятался. Правда, белка заметила меня и замерла. // Вводное слово
Я спрятался, правда белка заметила меня и замерла. // Союз
```

Но такой подход фактически говорит - считайте как хотите.

Например, в отношении аналогичного по статусу **однако** справочник уже меняет свои установки:

```
Я спрятался. Однако белка заметила меня и замерла.  // Союз
Я спрятался. Белка, однако, заметила меня и замерла. // Вводное слово
```

Обе трактовки сходятся на том, что если **правда/однако** стоят в середине простого предложения, то это вводные слова. Если же **правда/однако** стоят в начале, то возможны разные трактовки.

ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ:

Все предыдущее рассуждения относилось к неоднозначности "вводное слово - союз".
Рассмотрим еще неоднозначность "частица/вводное слово - наречие".

> ПРАВДА,
> 3. Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства  образа действия в значении «вправду», не обособляется:  **Слушай» а ты правда (=
> вправду) жена Алешки Скворцова или  это розыгрыш? (Ю.Нагибин).**

Это в точности такой же пример, как

```
– Вас чё, правда «сэр Николас» зовут?
```

В соответствии с чем делаем вывод: **правда** - **это наречие**. (дейсвительно, вправду, взаправду)

Справочник не регламентирует, что **правда** может функционировать в качестве частицы. Однако, может :

```
НЕ ПРАВДА ЛИ, частица.
Употребляется в функции вводного с целью привлечь внимание к сообщаемому, используется в вопросительных предложениях:
     Не правда ли, умница?
```

Таким образом во всех **вопросительных** предложениях, где можно заменить **правда** на **не правда ли**. **Правда** является вопросительной частицей и при этом оформляет вводную конструкцию. В следствие чего всегда обособляется!

```
Правда, красивые?
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваши старания. Справочники пусть себе путаются, а нам нужно найти короткое и верное решение. Или сказать, что его найти нельзя. Вот, к примеру, ваш последний вывод о том, что "правда" в середине предложение - это вводное слово. "Вы правда так считаете"? А в моей фразе это частица, хотя оно стоит в середине слова.

Comment: Добавил это в ответ.

Comment: Замечательно!  Хорошо бы еще составить текст урока,  чтобы  на  д а н н о м   примере просто и понятно объяснить ученице  тему  п а р н ы х   вариантов: как различить вводное слово,  наречие и частицу,  не допуская при этом  ни смысловых, ни стилевых ошибок. Тогда это будет действительно тот кирпичик знания, который принесет ей пользу (ну и нашим читателям тоже).

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий для Nadezhda к обсуждению темы (о парадоксе образования)**

***Недоученный хуже неученого. Полузнание хуже незнания*** (народные пословицы).

Есть такое выражение, как **«замыленный» глаз.** Так говорят об утрате свежести восприятия чего-либо, ставшего привычным, обыденным (этот термин применяется в некоторых профессиях).

А  что касается образования,  я бы сказала так: **«замыленное» сознание.** Вот изучает школьник какую-то тему, уже много прочитал книг, но так и не разобрался. Вроде бы все слова знакомые, понятные, а в целом  картина так и не проясняется. Почему же так происходит? На каком-то этапе сознание человека перестает воспринимать  такие слова вовсе, они становятся **информационным шумом.**

Вот и по теме вводных слова написано так много всего,  такое количество **«путаных» справочников,** что разобраться становится уже практически невозможно. Для этого нужно **чистое сознание,** и этот материал быстрее поймет человек, который впервые изучает предмет. Вот в этом **п а р а д о к с.**

А если все темы такие «замыленные», то как  освоить русское письмо не формально, а понимая его глубинный смысл, чтобы не сверять каждое предложение с примерами из учебника.

И тогда возникают вечные вопросы: **кто виноват и что делать?**  Можно ли вообще раскрыть  эту тему **с нуля, с чистого листа,  не пользуясь ничем,** написать просто и понятно для всех.  Я не знаю, а вы?  Может быть, попробуете дать ответ на вопрос в том формате, о котором я уже здесь говорила (в комментарии к уже полученному  ответу). Проверьте свои силы и возможности.

**Комментарий для user190920**

Знаете, чем мне нравится **информативный стиль**? Там в начале статьи дается **вывод**, чтобы читатель понимал, что он будет **иметь в итоге**, если потратит время на ее прочтение. Я считаю это уважением к людям, на внимание которых вы рассчитываете. Вы так не делаете, поэтому я начинаю вас читать **с конца.**

Вы пишете: Во всех вопросительных предложениях, где можно заменить «правда» на «не правда ли» слово «правда» является вопросительной частицей и при этом оформляет вводную конструкцию.

**Вывод неточный и неверный.**  Вопросительной является частица ЛИ, а вся конструкция – это обращение к собеседнику и, соответственно, поэтому вводное слово. Но вот я беру предложение **«Правда красивые?».** На письме нет запятой, в устной речи нет паузы. Это **частица,** хотя подстановку можно сделать.

В этом примере интонация **меняет статус слова**, а вы предлагаете формальный и очень частный прием для решения сложной проблемы. Вы так хотите **научить людей разбираться в этой теме**? Вряд ли они научатся это делать по такой методике, хотя ваше наблюдение, безусловно, верное. Его можно и нужно включить в тот формат, о котором я говорила.

Comment: "Может быть, попробуете дать ответ на вопрос в том формате, о котором я уже здесь говорила (в комментарии к уже полученному ответу). Проверьте свои силы и возможности." Ну так предложите свой вариант и мы все вместе его доработаем. Задавайте конкретные вопросы и мы будем конкретно отвечать

Comment: Я предлагала  "определенный формат"  к о н к р е т н о   вам после прочтения вашего ответа, а потом  Nadezhda после нашей дискуссии в комментариях. Таким образом, это уже   к о р р е к ц и я  заданного ранее вопроса в соответствии с определенными итогами обсуждения.  И вот еще что любопытно в вашем замечании – откуда появляется это "мы"?  Любите объединяться, чтобы увереннее себя чувствовать? Или я ошибаюсь в своей оценке?

Comment: Вы предложили и получили от меня коррекцию. В соответствии с этим вы должны либо переработать исходный текст либо задать уточняющие вопросы, а не предлагать дальше что-то делать за вас. Это не красиво. Насчет вашего последнего вопроса: "Не правда ли, что красивые?" -- тут частица. "Не правда ли, красивые?" -- тут вводная конструкция (состоящая из частицы).

Comment: Вы мне, право же, нравитесь иногда, с вами не соскучишься. Хотя бы настроение создаете, а то уж очень здесь бывает чопорно и церемонно.  Так говорите, долгов у меня много, но откуда? Я трачу на ответы  много времени, стараясь помочь людям получить нужную информацию. Вопросы же у меня все дискуссионные, в них нет личной заинтересованности. Это знания общего характера, которые идут на пользу и вам, и мне.

Comment: Или не идут? Это уж кому как,  вот вам, скорее всего, нет. Вы раздражаетесь, недовольны полученной оценкой, вы из тех, кому я мешаю.  Да, вопросы мне здесь лучше не задавать, но у меня есть в жизни другие «долги». Подробно рассказывать не имеет смысла, но внешне это выглядит так. Я не могу позволить вам давать неправильные и некачественные ответы на вопросы, заданные на этом ресурсе, и  постараюсь по возможности отслеживать это качество.

Comment: "Вопросы же у меня все дискуссионные, в них нет личной заинтересованности."--- "А у меня к этому вопросу, между прочим, личный интерес". Но дело не в вашей заинтересованности. Дело в ваших словах "Я не могу, а вы?" -- Не обманывайте, можете. По крайней мере начать можете, а мы(отвечающие) подкорректируем если что.

Comment: Нет, но вы действительно комик, даже злиться на вас не хочется. Личная заинтересованность была как исключение, единственный случай,  и то  «не прокатило». Слова же вы передергиваете, в тексте было: «Можно ли раскрыть тему с нуля? Я не знаю, а вы (знаете)?» Может быть, и могу, да только что мне за это будет, сколько минусов поставите? Работы там может оказаться немало, а  положительный баланс  вряд ли гарантирован.

Comment: "Может быть, и могу, да только что мне за это будет, сколько минусов поставите? Работы там может оказаться немало, а положительный баланс вряд ли гарантирован." -- Без труда не вытянешь и рыбку из пруда. Надо поработать, тогда и знания прибавятся. Вам за это будут минусы? Нам тоже. Мы в равном положении.

Answer (score 1):

**Даю свой ответ на вопрос**

1. В моем вопросе было две позиции: (1) как отличить частицу «правда» от вводного слова «правда» ,  (2) как разобраться в ситуации. В  заголовке был обозначен только  п.1, но, чтобы понять ситуацию, нужен более полный ответ со сравнительным  анализом двух слов (правда и во всяком случае).
2. **В  первой фразе** слово «правда»  **не обособляется:** это определяется по интонации в устной речи и по отсутствию запятой в речи письменной. Значит, слово «правда» употреблено в значении **частицы,** а это **разговорный вариант**.

Педагог предлагает ученице использовать необособленное наречие «в самом деле» с той же семантикой, но  нейтрального  стиля (так будет изящнее, говорит он). Все верно.

3. **Во второй фразе** девочка обособляет слово «правда», значит,  она использует его как вводное слово. Такое вводное слово имеет значение обращения к собеседнику с вопросом  о согласии во мнении (не правда ли?).  Теперь это **нейтральный стиль, правильная речь.**

Но она помнит предыдущее замечание и тут же поправляется:  меняет слово, да еще **не обособляет** его.  Тогда в вопросительном предложении  мы получаем фразу  с наречием  «в самом дЕле красивые?».  Но так можно сказать только в диалоге: «Какие красивые часики!» – В самом дЕле красивые»?

4. **В чем парадокс ситуации?** Педагог не учел вариант, когда  слово «правда» может иметь нейтральный стиль и значение вводного слова, это его недосмотр, впрочем, вполне простительный.

**А вывод такой:** правильное образование должно включать умение определять функцию слова и учитывать стиль **для всех случаев,** в то время как частное решение может  привести к неожиданному  результату.

Это должен быть комплекс знаний, который удобно было бы  освоить **как некий единый модуль,** подходящий для анализа  любых парных вариантов в теме вводных слов. Но пока никто не захотел описать такой блок-модуль.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**   (от 11.03.2021)

**В качестве вступления**

Изобретенный мною  **«модуль»** требовал своего воплощения, хотя  мне очень не хотелось заниматься этим. Но второй ответ всё-таки склоняет меня к тому, чтобы **хотя бы начать эту тему.**  Разумеется, с последующей коррекцией сказанного.

"Досье" на слово «***правда***» (часть речи, грамматическая роль, интонация, значение, стиль)

**1. ВВОДНОЕ СЛОВО** (на письме обособляется, произносится с  интонацией вводности, что хорошо фиксируется в речи)

(1)  **Значение соответствия действительности,** подтверждение сказанного ранее или согласие с  мнением другого лица (действительно, в самом деле); стиль разговорный

Отчего это во всех москвичах…есть что-то резкое...» – «Есть это, **прАвда**, есть...» – весело смеясь, сказал Степан Аркадьич.

(2) **значение уступки, признание ограниченной достоверности** суждения о чем-либо  (хотя, но, однако); стиль нейтральный

Там много ваших фотографий... Все, **правда**, размножены с одной.

Вводное слово «правда»  со значением уступки может использоваться в качестве **аналога союза** (хотя, но, однако)

Я хотел бы ее пригласить, **правда**, не уверен, что она согласиться.

Отдохнули хорошо, **правда**, к вечеру дождь пошел. Погуляли хорошо, **правда,** устали.  Погуляли хорошо,  устали, **правда**.

**Примечание.** Хотя вопрос об обособлении в этих примерах считается спорным, я полагаю, что это **вводные слова**. Явно просматривается  интонация вводности, в то время как частица должна выделяться ударением.

(3)  **обращение-вопрос к собеседнику** о подтверждении мнения (не правда ли?); стиль нейтральный.

В полном виде это выглядит как **вводное предложение**, в котором используется существительное «правда» в роли сказуемого (не правда ли это), но   условно неполное вводное предложение считается вводным словом  и произносится с интонацией вводности.

**ПрАвда**, красИвые?

**2. ЧАСТИЦА** (не обособляется и выделяется ударением, что хорошо фиксируется в устной речи; отсюда  кажущаяся «категоричность» мнения);
значение соответствия действительности (действительно, в самом деле).

Вас **прАвда** так зовут?   **ПрАвда** красивые? Я **прАвда** не хочу ехать.

Сравнить:

(1) Я **прАвда** не хочу ехать, но придется, наверное (частица, подчеркнутое соответствие действительности).

(2) Я, **правда**, не хочУ ехать, но придется, наверное (значение уступки).

**3. СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОЕ** (в функции сказуемого или подлежащего, требуется грамматический разбор и определение предикативной основы предложения)

Правда, что вы воевали? Это правда, что вы потеряли жену? Правда, что вас зовут Николас? – Да, это всё правда.

Правда ли это, нет ли – знали только они сами (И. Гончаров, Обрыв).
Может быть, именно в этом великая сермяжная правда (И. Ильф, Е. Петров).

Comment: Тут явно не хватает 4-ого пункта. Правда=Наречие. При этом пункты 1.1 2.1 и 2.2 можно объединить в 4-ый. А если очень хочется оставить слово частица (хотя справочник вводных слов Фармополь не регламентирует это), то можно говорить о союзном аналоге/частичном аналоге, соответствующем пункту 1.2. Пункт 1.1 сомнителен сам по себе, потому что, можно сравнить: "Дествительно, я купил это"(вводное слово) и "Я действительно купил это" (наречие). И "Правда, я купил это"( не звучит как действтиельно, звучит как Однако) и "Я правда купил это" (здесь уже звучит как действительно).

Comment: Смотрите, если у вас "Правда красивые?" ="Красивые правда?", то это явно не частица, ибо частицам не характерна перестановка. Это вводные конструкции (сюда же относим союзные аналоги). Либо же наречные вопросы. Наречия тоже допускают перестановки.

Comment: Да? Вот и составляйте СВОЙ МОДУЛЬ, а это мой, личный, он меня на данный момент  вполне  устраивает.  Вот только совершишь первый этап  восхождения к вершинам знания, как тебя тут же начинают сталкивать вниз. Критиковать только умеете.   Я же сказала –  с чистого листа, с нуля, без "путаных" справочников. Пользоваться только каноническими определениями и общепринятой классификацией вводных слов. Никаких предвзятых суждений о перестановках и т.д.!

Comment: А мне, пожалуй, нужно отдохнуть, а то мое сознание уж точно всё «замыленное». Желаю вам творческих успехов в освоении темы.  Будете у нас главным специалистом по вводным словам. Но не забывайте о том, что правильность теории проверяется на практике. Вот тогда и посмотрим, чей модуль лучше.

Comment: Да нет вы молодец, начали разбираться, копать, а не тупо копировать книжки. Просто, накинул чуток комментариев в продолжение ваших начинаний, но я тоже могу ошибаться насчет частиц. Я ими не занимался. По союзам я с вами полностью согласен. Всю перестановочную шелуху, выполняющую роль союзов, мы относим к вводным словам. Просто на основании перестановочности. Но запятыми, конечно, их не стоит выделять, если они оказываются привязаны к позиции.